# Why is my page fixed header overlays below the page content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using these style lines. Please check why header is showing below page content?
http://gtcgroups.com/ This is the website kindly tell me what i should do?

```
.header-normal .site-header.fixed-on  {
    background: #383780;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: you can try adding an z-index

Comment: Please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve]

Comment: `.header-normal .site-header.fixed-on {
    background: #383780;
    z-index: 80;
}` use z-index

Answer (score 0):

You have a `z-index:20` in your code.

You can use a `z-index:21;` on your header to make it appears above the page content.

Answer (score 0):

add z-index: 21 or more to your css and it will work

Answer (score 0):

z-index is used to define stack order of html elements. HTML elements with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

```
header{
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

It will increase page header stack order than page content stack order.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Fixed header z-index value is greater than z-index of the other sections

for example,

```
.header-normal .site-header.fixed-on  {
    background: #383780;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 130px;
    z-index: 9999;   
  }
```

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.

Comment: but i am facing one more problem that is the header is showing space below slider i am using this property                                                                                       .page-header-wrap{
 padding-top:39px;
}   but the problem is same

Comment: padding-top: 60px is adding for the div "page-header-wrap clearfix " thats why space is there

Comment: then what i should add